# Create 'remember me' feature in default django login view

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want to add remember me checkbox to my login view. I am using 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' view for login. I tried putting 'SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 360' and a checkbox named "remember_me" after reading related questions. But, this didn't help. Seems like this feature isn't there in the default login view. Or am I missing something?

Comment: [http://avivgr.blogspot.in/2009/05/how-to-add-remember-me-checkbox-to.html] can give you a good insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is not in default login view. But you extend the default login form. Add this remember me feature in extended form, and then declare log in url like this:

```
url(r'^login/$',
        auth_views.login,
        {'template_name': 'your/login/template.html', 'form':YourExtendedForm},
        name='auth_login'),
```

Also. There are many remember me snippets and projects out there. Do some googling and you will find working example in no time... like :https://github.com/jimfmunro/django-remember-me

Alan

Comment: yes I have taken the code from 'django-remember-me' view and 'form'. Works perfectly fine.