# Django : How to implement a 'remember me' radio button on a login page

Tags: python, django, authentication, caching, web-deployment

It can be tiring for my site users to always type in their login credentials manually whenever they visit my site regularly. So, how do I impliment such 'remember me' into my forms and have it functioning? Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Just add a new field in your form like this:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput)
    remember_me = forms.BoolenField()
```

And update the view:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            remember_me = form.cleaned_data['remember_me']
            user = authenticated(username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                if not remember_me:
                    request.session.set_expiry(0)  # <-- Here if the remember me is False, that is why expiry is set to 0 seconds. So it will automatically close the session after the browser is closed.

                # else browser session will be as long as the session  cookie time "SESSION_COOKIE_AGE"
                return redirect('/some/success/url')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()

        render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

#### Update

If you are using `AuthenticationForm`, then sub-class it like this:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    remember_me = forms.BooleanField(required=False)  # and add the remember_me field
```

And also sub-class your new view from [`LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView). Also override the `form_valid` method inside the View.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login

class UpdatedLoginView(LoginView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
       
        remember_me = form.cleaned_data['remember_me']  # get remember me data from cleaned_data of form
        if not remember_me:
            self.request.session.set_expiry(0)  # if remember me is 
            self.request.session.modified = True
        return super(UpdatedLoginView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Rather than creating a whole new login view, can you tell me to extend the existing `AuthenticationForm` present in `django.contrib.auth.forms` in forms.py

Comment: And does this need to make changes in urls.py cause the login url contains views.login i.e default login , do i need to change all the redirects in my templates to UpdatedLoginView

Comment: I implemented everything everyone suggested , i got a remember me key too and login is getting successful , Can you tell me how can i know if it is actully remembering me.

Comment: if you have unchecked remember me, then whenever you close the browser and open it again, then the server should prompt to login page whenever you want to go some page where login is required

Comment: Actually thats not happening , what to do . I check the remember me box and whenever i close browser and reopen and go to a page where a login is require , it dont ask me for login , but vice versa isnt going true.That is if i dont check the remember me , and go to page where i need login its still accepting me.

Comment: Do u suggest something by which if user unchecks the remember me box , and close the browser it should automatically log them out.

Comment: it isnt logging them out after closing browser

Comment: in that case, you need to debug. see what you are getting from `remember_me`

Comment: Can you please ellaborate.How can i debug what is remember_me responding

Comment: `print(remember_me)`

Comment: I did that , and actually its printing nothing

Comment: I dont use classbased views , i didnt understood what to put at the Updateloginview inheritence section

Comment: thats basic python stuff.

Comment: I debugged it , Actully the problem if in the code near remember_me somewhere , either i check or uncheck remember_me , the `request.session.get_expire_at_browser_close` is always showing `False`

Comment: Ah, i think i got it. you need to put another line `self.request.session.modified = True`. Please see my updated code. @Jidnyesh

Comment: I did that too , Everytime i open a new browser and put login details , checking remember me , a `session_key` is generated , But the `request.session.get_expire_at_browser_close` is still False , so it is creating a session but `request.session.get_expire_at_browser_close` is still false , Also when I logout of my own and login again , its not generating a `session_key` at all.Its `None` after i login again without closing browser

Comment: One more thing i need to tell , even before i login , its creating a `session_key` , Why so

Comment: I used it, when the checkbox is selected, and I close the browser( no matter chrome or mozila) it wont save the username and pass. next time I should enter them again, any solutions?

Comment: You can also sepcify expiry time individually by set_expiry().

Answer (score 5):

@ruddra answer is correct, but is not working as expected in Chrome browser. It is working on Firefox, though.

After a lot of reading, I was able to understand the problem. This might be useful for people who face the same problem.

When you visit ['sessions' section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/) on django project page, you see (under 'Browser-length sessions vs. persistent sessions'):

> Some browsers (Chrome, for example) provide settings that allow users to continue browsing sessions after closing and re-opening the browser. In some cases, this can interfere with the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE setting and prevent sessions from expiring on browser close. Please be aware of this while testing Django applications which have the SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE setting enabled.

With @ruddra code you efectively set cookies to last only for the current session:

> Firefox: session **is closed** when you close the browser
>
> Chrome: session is **not closed** when you close the browser

Anyways, if you shutdown the computer, stop all Chrome processes or logoff from your current session (at OS level), you can see that now the django session is over.

This is Chrome default behaviour, and I think there is not much to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can reference from this remember-me project:

https://github.com/jimfmunro/django-remember-me

and also a similar issue was solved in:
[Create 'remember me' feature in default django login view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594823/create-remember-me-feature-in-default-django-login-view)

You need to set session expiry period:

```
request.session.set_expiry(1209600) # 2 weeks
```

Django sessions are set to 2 weeks (SESSION_COOKIE_AGE defaults to 1209600 seconds) and will not expire when the browser is closed (SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE defaults to False)

But if it's a must you set a remember me checkbox option with backend functions, then you can do the following on your Login custom form.

```
remember_me = forms.BooleanField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxInput())

if not self.cleaned_data.get('remember_me'):
self.request.session.set_expiry(0)
```

Comment: Actually i wanted to ask what changes to make in code to make remember me key works , like session and cache in detail.

Comment: Im quite a starter therefore wanted prerequisites to do before adding remember me

Comment: You will need to add the session expiry period for it to work after successful login credentials validation or when you are starting the user session

Comment: But i dont have a login view at all , where do you expect me to put this code , im just using built in django authentication , any way to extend the built in login django form

Comment: Have updated the answer to include the essential parts

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea which is by adding another filed like below:

**secret_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)**

The main idea behind using the **secret_code** filed is to recover your username & password in login page.

Also i have thinking about another idea which is by storing your MAC address or IP address automatically but this is not going to work if you had switched to login from another device.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)? This package will handle most of the authentication needs and it has a built-in remember me field. It's highly customizable

Edit: allauth comes with builtin "Remember Me" field that will allow you to use remember me functionality out of the box. Most importantly it is highly customizable. You can add/delete whatever you want to each of the forms. Being a very popular package there are many tutorials online that explain how to use it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.